# Caching large static files for quick serving on Heroku

Tags: mongodb, caching, heroku, mongoengine, mongohq

I recently deployed a Flask app on Heroku. Right now the backend is all managed through MongoEngine. I have an issue though, which is that I have some fairly large static files (about 30 Mb in total) which I need to load very quickly. (It's an ML system).

I can't really find any documentation around how I would approach this, so any help would be appreciated. Also if I'm asking the wrong question please let me know. I'm basically just looking for a very fast way to load static files on a Heroku App.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Serving static assets of AWS S3](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3) is the recommended approach.

Comment: I think the OP wants to *read* them into dyno memory? If so, reading them yourself from S3 is not bad, I supopse. I've never tried putting them in git and including them in the slug (max slug size is now 200MB), but other than being inelegant I supopse that's the fastest way.

Comment: Serving them out of cloudfront which is backed by S3 will probably get you an additional speed boost.